# Youtube Player does not work

Tags: android, android-studio, youtube, youtube-data-api

Hii i write that code with a tutorial but it doesn't work. Please help me whats wrong with that??
I think it's because it is in a fragment but when i debug it on my device i get a connection error and no java error...

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeBaseActivity;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeInitializationResult;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayer;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView;

public class ItemTwoFragment extends Fragment {

public Player player;

public static ItemTwoFragment newInstance(){
    ItemTwoFragment fragment=new ItemTwoFragment();
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState){
    View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment2,container,false);
    player=new Player(view);
    return view;
    }
}
class Player extends YouTubeBaseActivity{
YouTubePlayerView player;
YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener onInitializedListener;

public Player(View view) {
    player=(YouTubePlayerView) view.findViewById(R.id.player);
    onInitializedListener=new YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean b) {
            youTubePlayer.loadPlaylist("ANak509iCl4&list=PLj9JLcynHDZ6Ymoz8GEWy0U9RDtRM4P_2");
        }

        @Override
        public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {

        }
    };
    player.initialize("AIzaSyCYuQjVhqjVA_I2tPMa-Egy4x-d7KFVFDQ",onInitializedListener);

}
}
```

Comment: Do you enabled the ACCESS_INTERNET permission at your app?

Comment: yes, i enabled it :)